# Sidebar Margin, How can I adjust it?

Tags: css, margin, sidebar

I'm using Avada theme 3.5.3 which provides great features.

Well, What is the problem? Actually, I can not adjust sidebar and page content gap. Please have look at my website [HERE](http://sciself.com/contact/)

Different CSS classes and IDs have been tested and none of them was helpful, e.g.:

```
<div id="content" style="float:left; margin: 0px">
<div id="sidebar" style="float:right; margin: 0px">
```

I know, it is an elementary task to set the gap between element, but the CSS code do not make any change.

Does this mean that CSS can not provide me a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you float the `content` to the left, and the `sidebar` to the right, changing the `margin` won't have an effect (unless maybe it gets bigger than the available width of the gap, but certainly not while the margin is smaller than the gap that is already there).

Float them both to the left (or right), then the margin will have an effect.

---

Keep in mind though, that by doing this, the outerside of either the `sidebar` or `content` (depending on whether you use `float:left` or `float:right`) will **NOT LINE UP** with the outerside of the elements in the header on that respective side (e.g. searchbar on the left, or menu buttons on the right).

Perhaps a better solution would be to adjust the `width` of the `content` and/or `sidebar`, instead of using margin. (Increasing the `width` will effectively decrease the gap, and vice versa.)

Comment: @Shaqpad - I've added some extra info you might want to take into consideration

Comment: Exactly, This is what I did. Have a look at above link, now the gap between sidebar and content looks better and the layout is responsive as well.